# What is the sequential-logic analog of a stack?

Tags: logic, fifo, sequential

If a queue in software is analogous to a register in hardware, in that they pass data through in a FIFO way, what type of circuit would give me the functionality of a stack (LIFO)?

Comment: A register is not a queue; the queue structure assumes some capacity to hold several values which enter and leave it in certain order. A register, on the other hand, can only hold one value.

Comment: *I should have said shift register, I apologize